# Pass array as value of annotation param in JavaPoet

Tags: java, code-generation, annotation-processing, javapoet, annotation-processor

Using JavaPoet I'm trying to annotate a class with an annotation which has **an array** as a parameter value i.e.

```
@MyCustom(param = { Bar.class, Another.class })
class Foo { 
}
```

I use `AnnotationSpec.builder` and its `addMember()` method:

```
List<TypeMirror> moduleTypes = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
AnnotationSpec annotationSpec = AnnotationSpec.builder(MyCustom.class)
   .addMember("param", "{ $T[] } ", moduleTypes.toArray() )
   .build();
builder.addAnnotation(annotationSpec);
```

Answer (score 1):

CodeBlock has a joining collector, and you can use that to stream this, doing something like the following (if for instance this was an enum).  You can do it for any types, just the map would change.

```
AnnotationSpec.builder(MyCustom.class)
   .addMember(
      "param",
      "$L",
      moduleTypes.stream()
         .map(type -> CodeBlock.of("$T.$L", MyCustom.class, type))
         .collect(CodeBlock.joining(",", "{", "}")))
   .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an optimal solution but passing an array to an annotation in JavaPoet can be done in the following way:

```
List<TypeMirror> moduleTypes = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
CodeBlock.Builder codeBuilder  = CodeBlock.builder();
boolean arrayStart = true;
codeBuilder.add("{ ");
for (TypeMirror modType: moduleTypes)
    if (!arrayStart)
        codeBuilder.add(" , ");
    arrayStart = false;
    codeBuilder.add("$T.class", modType);
codeBuilder.add(" }");

AnnotationSpec annotationSpec = AnnotationSpec.builder(MyCustom.class)
    .addMember("param", codeBuilder.build() )
    .build();
builder.addAnnotation(annotationSpec);
```